# How to Find a Gallery's ID

Tags: plugin-development, gallery

Can you please let me know how to find out a galley's ID? and Can we use this ID in CSS styling? if not how we can stylize two different galleries in diffident style?(to be honest I am not sure this is possible or not but I hope!)

Comment: The gallery CSS is automatically generated using both  an ID and a unique class. Right click your page and select element.

Answer (score 1):

The `[gallery]` shortcode supports specifying the gallery's id by supplying the `id` parameter. More on this in the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode).

However, using `id` might be contra productive if you wish to use two different styles of galleries across your site, in which case you would need to use the same style for a whole lot of `#ids` in your CSS - which you might not even know beforehand. Unfortunately there is not `class` attribute available. To accomodate this need you could remove the default gallery shortcode and add your own shortcode handler function replicating the functionality of [`gallery_shortcode`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/media.php#L671) while adding support for a `class` parameter or what you might need.

```
remove_shortcode('gallery', 'gallery_shortcode');
add_shortcode('gallery', 'my_gallery_shortcode');

function my_gallery_shortcode($attr) {
    ...
}
```

**EDIT**: Another, perhaps simpler, option to accomplish the same thing would be the create a wrapper shorttag for `gallery`:

```
add_shortcode('my_gallery', 'my_gallery_shortcode');

function my_gallery_shortcode($attr) {
    $attr = shortcode_atts(array('class' => 'gallery-wrapper'), $attr);
    $class = $attr['class'];
    unset($attr['class']);

    return '<div class="' . $class . '">' . gallery_shortcode($attr) . '</div>';
}
```

Comment: A [CSS3 Selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/), like **[`^=`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13352103/1287812)** could be handy, no?

Comment: Sure, that's a great solution. Turns out that selector has *way more* browser support than I thought.